# Opening a file in notepad and saving without corrupting

Tags: windows, file-transfer, file-management, file-permissions, notepad

I have a music file that I want to open in notepad and then `save as` to another location,  when I do this it corrupts the file.  How can I open and `save as` the file without corrupting?

I have tried changing encoding but it does not seem to work.

> **Background:**  This question may seem strange but I can't get admin access on my PC (nor can I get Windows to start) so I cannot `move` files (via cmd) and nor can I start file explorer. However I have discovered I can move them via notpad (I am basically trying to recover files from a broken PC that allows me to start notepad and move files to a USB).

Comment: Boot a healthy system (e.g. live CD Linux) and copy your files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file selection dialog in Notepad should allow you to copy files without opening them and saving them. In Notepad, use the `File` menu and select `Open...` or type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>. Then, use the file selection dialog like you would windows explorer to copy files. For instance, drag a music file onto another volume and drop it. This should allow you to copy music files without corruption.

Comment: Wow you are right!  thank you so much;  I am saved :)